# Game Center integration in sprite kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I've gone through multiple questions and tutorials but can't find anything that properly teaches how to integrate game center into a sprite kit game. Every example includes `[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)` which was first depreciated in iOS 6.0. I've checked ray wenderlich, 4 questions on here, and some other sources. I can't find ANYTHING.

Can anyone help me out?

Edit: I only want it for leaderboards and achievements, not match making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this is helpful, I just found that a few days ago, as I'm going through similar issues, but I didn't get a chance to test it yet, been too busy unfortunately.
But I'd like to know if that was a pointer in the right direction, let me know!

http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10844